# Using Slim and Render causes PHP Issue

Tags: php, view, twig, slim

I am using the slim framework to create a website and have views and twig in my project.  In my pages, I use php to help facilitate what html is rendered in my webpage.  An example is below

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>I ain't afraid of no bugs!</title>
   <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../_images/_logos/bug-hunter-icon.ico" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../_css/home.css">

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">    </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="_javascript/login.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="_javascript/sign_up.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php require 'header_login.php' ?> //problem
    <!--div banner, content-area, footer -->
  </body>

</html>
```

and then I render this page by

```
$app->render('home.php');
```

However, the html in header_login.php is not loaded onto the page.  Instead when I inspect the element, the page looks like

[image: The other html displayed is correct]

What I do not understand is why the code I am linking to is not being displayed there.  The code being imported is a simple navigation bar.  But even if I put echo "lala" on the pages, nothing php is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Read Twig documentation:
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html

```
{% include 'header_login.php' %}
```

Or see SlimPHP - PHP view

https://github.com/slimphp/PHP-View

You can see the difference with the Twig View

https://github.com/slimphp/Twig-View

Comment: I know you can use twig's templates, but I want to use php and should be able to.

Comment: I added URL's to both Twig and PHP views of slimPHP. You can see how to use each of them and how you can switch between them..

Answer (score 0):

If the `header_login.php` file is in the same directory as `home.php`, you should be able to change it to

`<?php require __DIR__ . '/header_login.php' ?>`

This tells PHP to load it from the same directory as the current file, rather than the directory of the script being executed.